# How to only allow URLs with specific parameter in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, piwik

I using Piwik to track my websites visitors. As a matter of "security" I only allow the access to `index.php` a few known IPs. My problem is that the Piwik opt-out snippet is only available via this `index.php`.

I tried to solve this via `RewriteRule`'s and `Location`/`Files` directives but I won't able to allow only the specific URL parameter and let others deny.

For all those people who don't know (much) Piwik but Apache here a the basic points:

- The administrative GUI is available via `index.php` which it's access is limited to known IPs.
- The Piwik opt-out snippet is **only** available via `index.php` with a known parameter set: `index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut&lang=DE`

What I want is:

- Deny access to `index.php` from all unknown IPs but known IPs. (done)
- Allow access to the opt-out parameter set for `index.php` from all IPs. (pending)

How to only allow URLs with specific parameter in Apache?

I tried:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
<Files "index.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/piwik-opt-out.html$ index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut [L]
<Location "/piwik-opt-out.html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Can you quickly post your rule you've got on `index.php` at the moment?

Comment: Done, @MarkHenderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can shrink the rules to just:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !action=optOut
RewriteRule index.php - [R=401]
```

Comment: The main thing to learn here is: the RewriteRule only works on the URL part, not on the parameter part. If you want to do actions on the parameter part, test the %{QUERY_STRING}.